# Google universal analytics showing unrelated referral link

Tags: magento, google-analytics, magento-1.7

I migrated Google's Universal Analytics into our magento system. Everything is tracking fine but found some unrelated referral links in that.( Please refer an Image)

[image]

As you can see in the image, It's showing payu.in as the Source/Medium. How come? Payu.in is the payment gateway we are using. Also it's has the transactions too. Like payu.in some other unrelated links are also showing in Source/Medium. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

I presume in your previous GA installation you had the [_setCampNOKey()](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiCampaignTracking#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setCampNOKey) setting in place to prevent payment gateways from showing up in the reports. This does no longer exist in UNiversal Analytics, you have to add your payment providers to the referral exclusion list in the property settings (under "Tracking Info / Referral Exclusion List").

Comment: `_setCampNOKey()` was not there but I added in the Referral Exclusion List. Let me check.